# Haskell Chinese Remainder theorem

Tags: haskell, chinese-remainder-theorem

I understand that in order for this function to work crtHasSolution has to be true first I'm having trouble proving that n could be a solution any ideas or tips in how to write or check that in haskell?

I know that the conditions for N are that it has to be bigger or equal to 0 and smaller then m which is the product of all the mod bases.

[image: notes from where conclusion came from]

```
crtHasSolution :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Bool
crtHasSolution as ms = length as > 0 &&
                       length ms > 0 &&
                       length as == length ms &&
                       all (>=0) as &&
                       all (>=2) ms &&
                       pairwise_coprime ms

-- Is a given number a solution to a CRT problem?
-- usage: crtIsSolution n as ms = ans
-- assures: ans == True, if crtHasSolution as ms == True and n is a solution
--          ans == False, otherwise

crtIsSolution :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Bool
crtIsSolution n as ms = crtHasSolution as ms &&
                        n >= 0 &&
                        n < m
                        where m =
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7KNl.png)

Comment: What did you try so far ? It would be better if you could show your attempt and we then help you at parts where you are stuck.

Comment: if you look at the code picture that is what i have tried so far but im not sure if that's correct

Comment: for future reference, just copy/paste your code, rather than screenshotting it.

Answer (score 4):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Systematic_search):

> It is easy to check whether a value of `x` is a solution: it suffices to compute the remainder of the Euclidean division of `x` by each **[`m_i`]**.

If `` x `mod` m_i /= a_i `` for any `i`, then `x` is not a solution.

This smacks of homework, so rather than give you a one-liner that computes this, I'm going to give you some leading questions for your implementation of `crtIsSolution n as ms`:

- Is `n` a solution if `ms` and `as` are empty?
- If you can compute whether `` n `mod` m_0 == a_0 `` and whether `n` is a solution for `ms_0` and `as_0`, can you compute whether `n` is a solution for `m_0:ms_0` and `a_0:as_0`?